# Vinylic Nucleophilic Substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

While reading "Francis A. Carey, Richard J. Sundberg - Advanced Organic Chemistry Part A. Structure and Mechanisms-Springer (2007)", I came across the following schematic for addition of electrophiles to vinyl ethers:

[image: electrophilic addition to alkoxy alkene]

I understand that such a reaction has application in polymer chemistry. For example, under the right acidic conditions, methylvinylether will form polyvinylmethylether:

[image: polymerization of methylvinylether to polyvineylmethylether under acidic conditions]

Under what conditions will the electrophile react with the lone-pair of oxygen instead of the $\beta$-Carbon?

In another section, I found that hard-hard and soft-soft interactions are preferred over hard-soft interactions:

[image: hard-hard, soft-soft, and hard-soft interactions]

Many questions arise from reading this. Is the lone pair on the oxygen atom hard or soft? And accordingly, what kind of electrophile should be used? Do stearic factors play a role?

It has been pointed out in the comments that addition of electrophile to oxygen is a reversible and non-productive. What I was thinking was something like this:

[image: two electrophilic additions to vinyl ethers]

I guess the reaction could be called a **vinylic nucleophilic substitution**.

Comment: Addition of an electrophile such as a proton to the oxygen of methyl vinyl ether (MVE) is a reversible, non-productive event. MVE in the presence of $\ce{H3O+}$ gives hydrolysis to acetaldehyde. With methanol/$\ce{H+}$ the dimethyl acetal of acetaldehyde is produced.